# IIS 7.5 Compression isn't working

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7, compression

I am trying to get IIS 7.5 compression working. It sounds so simple by all the blogs, but it isn't working for me. I am using asp.net mvc if that matters. I am testing this locally, and I am using IIS 7.5, not cassini. I have read and tried every article I can find. I have made sure the static and dynamic compression modules are installed. I have tried several articles like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754668%28WS.10%29.aspx), that talk about setting it up using appcmd. I have tried several articles like [this](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/98538.aspx), that configure the settings in the web.config. I have checked the mime types as discussed in articles where js files were only working sometimes (I can't post the link because I am a new user and limited to 2 links). I have created action filters for mvc as discussed in many blogs (again, I can't post the links)

None of the methods are compressing anything. No css, no js, no pages... nothing. I can even step through the code, I see that the action filter is running, I even see it running the following two lines, and yet fiddler shows no compression.

```
response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

I must be having a huge brain fart and missing something really stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Does IIS compression just not run when running locally? Does the IIS compression not work with MVC because of the routing or something?

Any suggestions/tests/info?

Comment: I've used it with MVC and it did indeed work. I assume you edited your web.config appropriately and installed the modules under IIS, right? What's your OS? Windows 2008 or 7? Not saying that should matter, but the feature implementation might be different.

Comment: I have the same problem with IIS 7.5 on windows 2008 and a static content website. from the server config it says its set up and the site itself. but no compression and nothing written to the cached content folder. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the staticContent element to the web.config.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent